# Network connection not working while calling Xiaomi 10T

Tags: xiaomi, mobile-network

My boyfriend and I call a lot, and for the last few months we noticed that he isn't able to use his 5G network when we are calling. We call a lot and we don't always have a wifi connection, so it is necessary for us to fix this issue.

His profider is Telford.
The phone in question is the Xiaomi 10T.
He is currently using MIUI 13.

We appreciate any tips and fixes <3

Comment: Voice over 5g is as far as I know not yet available in most mobile networks, so if a call comes the phone has to switch to LTE or UMTS or GSM (depends on what is available in your country and your mobile network provider). And for LTE voice only works if VoLTE is active and available by your MNO.

Comment: The simplest solution would be using  VoIP, eg whatsapp calls. As mentioned by @Robert , device should fallback to LTE and VoLTE while calls are made. Can you share the output after doing this: (1) Dial \*#\*#4636#\*#\* (2) choose phone information (3) then the drop down menu and tell me what's being shown under "IMS Status"

Comment: @Robert can u review my comment once?